# Package wasm file inside angular custom elements bundle

Tags: angular, webpack, element, webassembly

I'm creating a custom elements bundle (`my-elements.js`) with angular v14 that use a wasm library. I want to host this bundle on a web-server and provide it as a library that anyone can use.

As a test, I hosted an index.html on localhost, that has a link to https://my-webserver.com/my-elements.js. The elements bundle gets downloaded correctly but then it tries to download the wasm file from localhost and not from my-webserver.com.

I've tried setting up webpack to bundle all the angular build js files in dist together with the wasm library into a single file but I could not get this to work. The browser downloads my-elements.js but doesn't even try to download the wasm file.

Here's my webpack config:

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    mode: "production",
    entry: "./dist/custom-elements/main.js",
    output: {
        filename: "custom-elements.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.wasm$/,
                use: ["wasm-loader"]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

I also tried following this guide to customise my angular build with webpack: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/12/09/angular-webpack.
Here's my custom-webpack-config:

```
module.exports = {
    "module": {
        "rules": [
            {
                "test": /\.wasm$/,
                "use": ["wasm-loader"]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

but this gave me some seemingly unrelated error messages:

```
[error] Error: NOT SUPPORTED: keyword "id", use "$id" for schema ID
    at Object.code (/home/user/custom-elements/node_modules/ajv/dist/vocabularies/core/id.js:6:15)
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Have you found a better way?

Comment: I'm afraid not.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a dirty solution that works but I don't like it.

I'm building my project with `ng build --output-hashing=none`.

I then located where the wasm library is being referenced in `dist/runtime.js`:

`c=fetch(s.p+""+a+".module.wasm")`

I manually prefixed that with my web-site's domain:

`c=fetch("https://my-webserver.com/" + s.p+""+a+".module.wasm")`

I then bundle all of the js files that angular's build outputted into the dist folder into a single gz file:
`cat dist/custom-elements/*.js | gzip > test/elements.js.gz`

This will have to do until I find a better solution.